# How to access a drawable in android Java

Tags: android, xml, mobile

I am developing an android app and I  need to know how to reference a drawable in my java code. The image/drawable is in my drawable folder and it is referenced in my xml. How do I then access it in my activity (Java code).

In my xml I have

```
android:src="@drawable/medkit"
```

and in my android activity class:

```
  ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("In plaster walls, strips of metal mesh bent at right angles and embedded in corners of ceilings and walls to prevent the plaster from cracking.");
      child.add( R.drawable.ic_medkit );
 child.add( R.drawable.medkit );
```

Comment: Please make your question clear.

Comment: R.drawable values are not strings.

Comment: R.drawable.ic_medkit will be a integer so use getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_medkit)

Answer (score 1):

```
   int resid= R.drawable.ic_medkit
```

will be a integer so use

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resid)
```

so in your case

```
child.add(0,String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_medkit));
getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(child.get(0)))
```

Comment: This seems to bring out a number as opposed to the actual image I am trying to retrieve

Comment: using that integer you will be able to get respective drawable, as all the drawable are index in R.java file

Comment: the number I am getting is 2130837568 so I am trying this 
`ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("In plaster walls, strips of metal mesh bent at right angles and embedded in corners of ceilings and walls to prevent the plaster from cracking.");
       child.add(0,String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_medkit));
       getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(child.get(2130837568)));
      childItems.add(child);` which doesnt seem to do the trick

Comment: getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(child.get(0))); like this it should be the index not the number

Comment: or as getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(21‌​30837568);